# Not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, oledb, .net-4.5

I have a problem connecting to the database.It keeps giving this error:
**provider local machine is not registered.**
My connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Users.accdb
```

•I installed the driver

•I restarted my computer

•My computer is 64bit

**Thank you for your help**

Comment: 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: My computer is 64bit

Comment: The ACE need to be same version of Office installed on machine.  The ACE is located in a folder like C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15 with 15 being the version in the Provider.  If you do not have office installed on machine then you need to download the runtime version of ACE.

Comment: There are 3 folders in this location OFFICE11, OFFICE12, OFFICE14